# Can we import local csv file data in Django?

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, file-handling

i dont to develop a search system in which we are going to import data from csv file which is local file in our computer, i want to import the csv file in django to store it's value in dictionary. but i am not able to import the data in django.

here is code and image,

[image: in this image you can see error]

and this is view.py file code in which i add csv

```
from unicodedata import name
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import context
import csv

def index(request):
    context = {'name':'xyz'}
    file = open("railway_stations.csv")
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    rows = []
    d = dict()
    for row in csvreader:
       rows.append(row)
    for r in rows:
       d.update({r[0]:r[1]})
       print(r[0]) 

    print(d["Prescot"])
    file.close()
    return render(request, 'home.html',context)
```

and my railway_stations.csv file is in following image [image: click on this image to see directory of csv file]\

please please suggest me who to do it. (who to import csv to view.py file)

i just try simple import csv to import the csv,
i am expecting how to import the csv file in a view.py file so that i am render all the data in html file.also i do it in python in fine way but now i am facing difficulty in django

or you can also suggest me good way to import csv file and show all the data in html or in browser.

Comment: The simplest solution at this moment is, right-clcik on the `railway_stations.csv` and choose copy relative path, then use that path inside `open`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import csv file in django by using the static folder.

first you have to create the folder in your app (where manage.py is located)
and add it path to the `setting.py` [image: see image here]

how you can check this setting is  working or not in your browser like

[image: like this]

and paste your csv file inside your `static folder` as you can see my folder

[image: here]

now add csv file directory path to `view.py` file

the modified code is look like this

```
from unicodedata import name
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import context
import csv

def index(request):
    context = {'name':'xyz'}
    file = open("static/railway_stations.csv")
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    rows = []
    d = dict()
    for row in csvreader:
       rows.append(row)
    for r in rows:
       d.update({r[0]:r[1]})
       print(r[0]) 

    print(d["Prescot"])
    file.close()
    return render(request, 'home.html',context)
```

now run the server and then you can not finde any error.

csv value is printed in my console as you can see in this image

[image: here]

[image: here]

that it's, it is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Add your file to static folder and in the view file put that :

```py
from unicodedata import name
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import context

# add this line
from django.templatetags.static import static
    
import csv
        
def index(request):
    context = {'name':'xyz'}
    file = open(static('railway_stations.csv'))
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    rows = []
    d = dict()
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
    for r in rows:
        d.update({r[0]:r[1]})
            print(r[0])

    print(d["Prescot"])
    file.close()
    return render(request, 'home.html',context)
```

Comment: thanks for helping me, before you answer i also figure it out by my own.